# How can I view the events of RbxGui methods?

Tags: lua, roblox

So, I was making a plugin for ROBLOX Studio, and got caught on the RbxGui methods. 
I created a slider inside a frame using

```
local sGui = Instance.new("ScreenGui", game.CoreGui)
local PaceFrame = Instance.new("Frame", sGui)
PaceFrame.Size = UDim2.new(0, 210, 0, 200)
local PaceSlider = RbxGui.CreateSlider(10,200,UDim2.new(0, 5, 0, 175))
PaceSlider.Parent = PaceFrame
```

So my question is, how can I detect when the slider value is moved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RbxGui.CreateSlider](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php/CreateSlider_%28Function%29) returns two values, a frame for the slider as well as an IntValue with the position.

You should be able to use [IntValue.Changed](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php/Changed_%28Event%29/value) to detect changes:

```
local sGui = Instance.new("ScreenGui", game.CoreGui)
local PaceFrame = Instance.new("Frame", sGui)
PaceFrame.Size = UDim2.new(0, 210, 0, 200)
local PaceSlider, PaceSliderPosition = RbxGui.CreateSlider(10,200,UDim2.new(0, 5, 0, 175))
PaceSlider.Parent = PaceFrame
PaceSliderPosition.Changed:connect(function(position)
    print("Slider position is now " .. position)
end)
```